# Access denied to: https://mvnrepository.com/org/springframework and'parent.relativePath' points at no local POM @ line 5, column 10 @

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, maven

Im facing this problem when migrating from spring boot 2.7.x with java 8 to spring boot 3.2.0 with java 21. Maven version: 3.6.2.

I didn't have this problem before changing spring boot and java versions, the project and maven builds where running just fine

I have been using spring initzializr plugin to check for any differences between my pom and the created by the initzializr and there's no differences.

I have searched for a lot of solutions over the internet but couldn't find anything related to the problem i am facing.

This is my pom.xml file

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>3.2.0</version>
        <relativePath/> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
    </parent>
    <groupId>uy.com.bse</groupId>
    <artifactId>ServiciosIntranetSpring</artifactId>
    <version>1.0</version>
    <name>DemoSpring</name>
    <description>demo project</description>
    <properties>
        <java.version>21</java.version>
        <maven.compiler.source>${java.version}</maven.compiler.source>
        <maven.compiler.target>${java.version}</maven.compiler.target>
    </properties>
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web-services</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <!-- Base de datos y drivers -->

        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.oracle.database.jdbc</groupId>
            <artifactId>ojdbc8</artifactId>
            <scope>runtime</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.h2database</groupId>
            <artifactId>h2</artifactId>
            <scope>runtime</scope>
        </dependency>


        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.poi</groupId>
            <artifactId>poi-ooxml</artifactId>
            <version>3.11</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>wsdl4j</groupId>
            <artifactId>wsdl4j</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>jakarta.xml.bind</groupId>
            <artifactId>jakarta.xml.bind-api</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.glassfish.jaxb</groupId>
            <artifactId>jaxb-runtime</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.cxf</groupId>
            <artifactId>cxf-spring-boot-starter-jaxws</artifactId>
            <version>3.4.5</version> <!-- Use the latest version available -->
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.cxf</groupId>
            <artifactId>cxf-rt-transports-http</artifactId>
            <version>3.4.5</version>
        </dependency>

    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <configuration>
                    <image>
                        <builder>paketobuildpacks/builder-jammy-base:latest</builder>
                    </image>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>

</project>
```

My maven settings.xml file

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<settings xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/SETTINGS/1.1.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/settings-1.1.0.xsd" xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/SETTINGS/1.1.0"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">

  
  <profiles>
    <profile>
      <repositories>
        <repository>
          <releases>
            <updatePolicy>never</updatePolicy>
          </releases>
          <snapshots>
            <enabled>false</enabled>
            <updatePolicy>daily</updatePolicy>
          </snapshots>
          <id>redhat-ga-repository</id>
          <name>Red Hat GA repository</name>
          <url>http://maven.repository.redhat.com/ga/</url>
        </repository>
      </repositories>
      <pluginRepositories>
        <pluginRepository>
          <releases>
            <updatePolicy>never</updatePolicy>
          </releases>
          <snapshots>
            <enabled>false</enabled>
            <updatePolicy>daily</updatePolicy>
          </snapshots>
          <id>redhat-ga-repository</id>
          <name>Red Hat GA repository</name>
          <url>https://maven.repository.redhat.com/ga/</url>
        </pluginRepository>
      </pluginRepositories>
      <id>redhat-ga-repository</id>
    </profile>
    <profile>
      <repositories>
        <repository>
          <releases>
            <updatePolicy>never</updatePolicy>
          </releases>
          <snapshots>
            <enabled>false</enabled>
            <updatePolicy>daily</updatePolicy>
          </snapshots>
          <id>maven-central</id>
          <name>Maven Central</name>
          <url>https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/</url>
        </repository>
      </repositories>
      <pluginRepositories>
        <pluginRepository>
          <releases>
            <updatePolicy>never</updatePolicy>
          </releases>
          <snapshots>
            <enabled>false</enabled>
            <updatePolicy>daily</updatePolicy>
          </snapshots>
          <id>maven-central</id>
          <name>Maven Central</name>
          <url>https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/</url>
        </pluginRepository>
      </pluginRepositories>
      <id>maven-central</id>
    </profile>
    <profile>
      <repositories>
        <repository>
          <releases>
            <updatePolicy>never</updatePolicy>
          </releases>
          <snapshots>
            <enabled>false</enabled>
            <updatePolicy>daily</updatePolicy>
          </snapshots>
          <id>maven-ibm</id>
          <name>Maven IBM</name>
          <url>https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.ibm.websphere.appserver.runtime/</url>
        </repository>
      </repositories>
      <pluginRepositories>
        <pluginRepository>
          <releases>
            <updatePolicy>never</updatePolicy>
          </releases>
          <snapshots>
            <enabled>false</enabled>
            <updatePolicy>daily</updatePolicy>
          </snapshots>
          <id>maven-ibm</id>
          <name>Maven IBM</name>
          <url>https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.ibm.websphere.appserver.runtime/</url>
        </pluginRepository>
      </pluginRepositories>
      <id>maven-ibm</id>
    </profile>
    <profile>
      <repositories>
        <repository>
          <releases>
            <updatePolicy>never</updatePolicy>
          </releases>
          <snapshots>
            <enabled>false</enabled>
            <updatePolicy>daily</updatePolicy>
          </snapshots>
          <id>jboss-public-repository</id>
          <name>JBoss Public</name>
          <url>https://repository.jboss.org/nexus/content/groups/public-jboss/</url>
        </repository>
      </repositories>
      <pluginRepositories>
        <pluginRepository>
          <releases>
            <updatePolicy>never</updatePolicy>
          </releases>
          <snapshots>
            <enabled>false</enabled>
            <updatePolicy>daily</updatePolicy>
          </snapshots>
          <id>jboss-public-repository</id>
          <name>JBoss Public</name>
          <url>https://repository.jboss.org/nexus/content/groups/public-jboss/</url>
        </pluginRepository>
      </pluginRepositories>
      <id>jboss-public-repository</id>
    </profile>
    <profile>
      <repositories>
        <repository>
          <releases>
            <updatePolicy>never</updatePolicy>
          </releases>
          <snapshots>
            <enabled>false</enabled>
            <updatePolicy>daily</updatePolicy>
          </snapshots>
          <id>repository-apache-org</id>
          <name>Apache Repository</name>
          <url>https://repository.apache.org/content/groups/public/</url>
        </repository>
      </repositories>
      <pluginRepositories>
        <pluginRepository>
          <releases>
            <updatePolicy>never</updatePolicy>
          </releases>
          <snapshots>
            <enabled>false</enabled>
            <updatePolicy>daily</updatePolicy>
          </snapshots>
          <id>repository-apache-org</id>
          <name>Apache Repository</name>
          <url>https://repository.apache.org/content/groups/public/</url>
        </pluginRepository>
      </pluginRepositories>
      <id>repository-apache-org</id>
    </profile>
    <profile>
      <repositories>
        <repository>
          <releases>
            <updatePolicy>never</updatePolicy>
          </releases>
          <snapshots>
            <enabled>false</enabled>
            <updatePolicy>daily</updatePolicy>
          </snapshots>
          <id>jboss-nexus</id>
          <name>jboss-nexus</name>
          <url>https://repository.jboss.org/nexus/content/groups/public/</url>
        </repository>
      </repositories>
      <pluginRepositories>
        <pluginRepository>
          <releases>
            <updatePolicy>never</updatePolicy>
          </releases>
          <snapshots>
            <enabled>false</enabled>
            <updatePolicy>daily</updatePolicy>
          </snapshots>
          <id>jboss-nexus</id>
          <name>jboss-nexus</name>
          <url>https://repository.jboss.org/nexus/content/groups/public/</url>
        </pluginRepository>
      </pluginRepositories>
      <id>jboss-nexus</id>
    </profile>
    <profile>
      <activation>
        <activeByDefault>true</activeByDefault>
      </activation>
      <properties>
        <sonar.host.url>http://localhost:9000</sonar.host.url>
      </properties>
      <id>sonar</id>
    </profile>
    <profile>
      <activation>
        <activeByDefault>true</activeByDefault>
      </activation>
      <repositories>
        <repository>
          <releases>
            <updatePolicy>never</updatePolicy>
          </releases>
          <snapshots>
            <enabled>false</enabled>
            <updatePolicy>never</updatePolicy>
          </snapshots>
          <id>ibm-maven-repo</id>
          <name>ibm-maven-repo</name>
          <url>http://public.dhe.ibm.com/ibmdl/export/pub/software/websphere/wasdev/maven/repository/</url>
        </repository>
      </repositories>
      <pluginRepositories>
        <pluginRepository>
          <releases>
            <updatePolicy>never</updatePolicy>
          </releases>
          <snapshots>
            <enabled>false</enabled>
            <updatePolicy>never</updatePolicy>
          </snapshots>
          <id>ibm-maven-repo</id>
          <name>ibm-maven-repo</name>
          <url>http://public.dhe.ibm.com/ibmdl/export/pub/software/websphere/wasdev/maven/repository/</url>
        </pluginRepository>
      </pluginRepositories>
      <id>standard-extra-repos</id>
    </profile>
    <profile>
      <repositories>
        <repository>
          <releases>
            <updatePolicy>never</updatePolicy>
          </releases>
          <snapshots>
            <enabled>false</enabled>
            <updatePolicy>daily</updatePolicy>
          </snapshots>
          <id>maven-archetype</id>
          <name>MavenArchetype</name>
          <url>https://mvnrepository.com/</url>
        </repository>
      </repositories>
      <pluginRepositories>
        <pluginRepository>
          <releases>
            <updatePolicy>never</updatePolicy>
          </releases>
          <snapshots>
            <enabled>false</enabled>
            <updatePolicy>daily</updatePolicy>
          </snapshots>
          <id>maven-archetype</id>
          <name>MavenArchetype</name>
          <url>https://mvnrepository.com/</url>
        </pluginRepository>
      </pluginRepositories>
      <id>maven-archetype-repository</id>
    </profile>
    <profile>
      <repositories>
        <repository>
          <releases>
            <updatePolicy>never</updatePolicy>
          </releases>
          <snapshots>
            <enabled>false</enabled>
            <updatePolicy>daily</updatePolicy>
          </snapshots>
          <id>RedHat-EA</id>
          <name>RedHatEA</name>
          <url>https://maven.repository.redhat.com/earlyaccess/all/</url>
        </repository>
      </repositories>
      <pluginRepositories>
        <pluginRepository>
          <releases>
            <updatePolicy>never</updatePolicy>
          </releases>
          <snapshots>
            <enabled>false</enabled>
            <updatePolicy>daily</updatePolicy>
          </snapshots>
          <id>RedHat-EA</id>
          <name>RedHatEA</name>
          <url>https://maven.repository.redhat.com/earlyaccess/all/</url>
        </pluginRepository>
      </pluginRepositories>
      <id>RedHatEA</id>
    </profile>

  </profiles>
  <activeProfiles>
    <activeProfile>redhat-ga-repository</activeProfile>
    <activeProfile>jboss-public-repository</activeProfile>
    <activeProfile>maven-central</activeProfile>
    <activeProfile>maven-ibm</activeProfile>
    <activeProfile>repository-apache-org</activeProfile>
    <activeProfile>jboss-nexus</activeProfile>
    <activeProfile>maven-archetype-repository</activeProfile>
  <activeProfile>RedHatEA</activeProfile>
  </activeProfiles>
  <pluginGroups>
    <pluginGroup>org.sonarsource.scanner.maven</pluginGroup>
  </pluginGroups>
</settings>
```

and this is the error in the console

INFO] Downloading from central: https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/org/springframework/boot/spring-boot-starter-parent/3.2.0/spring-boot-starter-parent-3.2.0.pom
[ERROR] [ERROR] Some problems were encountered while processing the POMs:
[FATAL] Non-resolvable parent POM for uy.com.bse:ServiciosIntranetSpring:1.0: Could not transfer artifact org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-parent:pom:3.2.0 from/to maven-archetype (https://mvnrepository.com/): Access denied to: https://mvnrepository.com/org/springframework/boot/spring-boot-starter-parent/3.2.0/spring-boot-starter-parent-3.2.0.pom and 'parent.relativePath' points at no local POM @ line 5, column 10
@
[ERROR] The build could not read 1 project -> [Help 1]
[ERROR]
[ERROR]   The project uy.com.bse:ServiciosIntranetSpring:1.0 (C:\bse\workspaces\springProjects\ServiciosIntranetSpring\pom.xml) has 1 error
[ERROR]     Non-resolvable parent POM for uy.com.bse:ServiciosIntranetSpring:1.0: Could not transfer artifact org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-parent:pom:3.2.0 from/to maven-archetype (https://mvnrepository.com/): Access denied to: https://mvnrepository.com/org/springframework/boot/spring-boot-starter-parent/3.2.0/spring-boot-starter-parent-3.2.0.pom and 'parent.relativePath' points at no local POM @ line 5, column 10 -> [Help 2]
[ERROR]
[ERROR] To see the full stack trace of the errors, re-run Maven with the -e switch.
[ERROR] Re-run Maven using the -X switch to enable full debug logging.
[ERROR]
[ERROR] For more information about the errors and possible solutions, please read the following articles:
[ERROR] [Help 1] http://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/MAVEN/ProjectBuildingException
[ERROR] [Help 2] http://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/MAVEN/UnresolvableModelException

Comment: It looks like your maven settings are wonky, what do your repository URLs look like in your maven settings?

Comment: @lane.maxwell i just added the maven version and the setting.xml file to the post

Comment: Deactivate the profile, maven-archetype-repository, and try it again.  You probably should consider reviewing your maven settings.  Unless you're pulling down protected artifacts from redhat, IBM, JBoss, etc, you do not need to add those repos, they are mirrored in maven central.

Comment: Remove `https://mvnrepository.com` this because it's not a maven repository...